# Scrapy works on local, but does not on production

Tags: python, django, deployment, web-scraping, scrapy

I have deployed my Django+Scrapy project, have running `scrapyd`. But when I try to run the spider, it finishes without actually scrapping info with those stats:

```
{'memusage/startup': 92348416,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 628, 
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 1,
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 21, 22, 6, 38, 333018), 
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4992,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 21, 22, 6, 33, 894037), 
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'memusage/max': 92348416,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 1}
```

Does that mean that my first request got rejected with `403 error`? W**hy that might work on local, but does not on production?**
 As I have read that might be caused by wrong `USER_AGENT` setting, but i have already set this like:

```
USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/'
```

As I said - it works on local, not on production.
**P.S.** Here are stats from the same spider running on local:

```
{
"start_time": "2018-05-22 14:25:45.857504",
"scheduler/enqueued/disk": "89",
"scheduler/enqueued": "89",
"scheduler/dequeued/disk": "89",
"scheduler/dequeued": "89",
"downloader/request_count": "101",
"downloader/request_method_count/GET": "101",
"downloader/request_bytes": "39724",
"downloader/response_count": "101",
"downloader/response_status_count/200": "101",
"downloader/response_bytes": "1901849",
"response_received_count": "101",
"request_depth_max": "1",
"file_count": "88",
"file_status_count/uptodate": "77",
"item_scraped_count": "88",
"file_status_count/downloaded": "11",
"finish_time": "2018-05-22 14:26:31.596248",
"finish_reason": "finished",
}
```

Comment: `'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 1` may be this is some kind of IP ban on your production

Comment: @gangabass hmm, your words might have a reason. I have a project with ~15 spiders, I have tested that on smallest 2, and got that `403 error`, but now I tested on another 2, and voila - they worked! But why does that ban appeared? I am deploying my project on DigitalOcean btw. Can I some how bypass it?

Comment: @Chiefir use proxies

Comment: @Umair, yep, I have already read a bit about that. But can you tell me from where can I get a list of proxy ips? Is this some kind of service or what should I search for?

Comment: There are plenty of proxy providers available. Just google it. I personally use stormproxies, they are $39/month